How to fix an old corrupted SD card that is completely unrecognized by the device?
I have a Samsung 8 GB SD card that isn't working. I watched tutorials on YouTube, and followed their steps. I changed devices, changed the drive letter, used chkdsk command and all other steps without formatting it. Only method left to try is to format it and use recovery software to redeem the files.
I wanted to ask this because I am not sure about formatting it because all the devices I used this SD card doesn't even recognize that it is a SD card, not even as a corrupted one. Is there any other professional methods to retrieve my files without formatting it? Are there technicians who can retrieve my files using physical methods? I saw on YouTube (I'm not sure if it's legit) a guy sanding down the surface of the SD card using a sand paper and then connecting wires to the emerged terminals. Is this a way a professional that can safely retrieve my files? Or do they have any other advanced techniques or hardware or software tools to recover it, that I don't have access to?
I have my childhood and family photos in it. They are very important. Any help would be highly appreciated

Yes, there are commercial data recovery services. If the data is of great value, get a cost estimate and request a statement for the chances of success. Each thing you try is going to reduce chances that a professional might recover anything.

I sorta get what everyone's doing here but I feel like the rollback wars and arguments in the comments are getting a bit heated. Chill people
